# Why is my boolean keep showing up no instead of either yes or no?

Tags: c++, boolean

Learning C++ here. If you execute my code it should ask you five guesses and then ask you to play again by picking y for yes or n for no. However, I am getting stuck with choosing either where both choices is showing up "no" and I don't know what's wrong with my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void PrintIntro();
void PlayGame();
bool AskToPlayAgain();
string GetGuess();


int main() 
{
// the entry point of our program
// calling a function declaration

PrintIntro();
PlayGame();
AskToPlayAgain();
return 0; // exit the application
}


string GetGuess() 
{
// get a guess from the player
cout << "Enter your guess: ";
string Guess = "";
getline(cin, Guess);

// print the guess back to them
cout << "Your guess was: ";
cout << Guess;
cout << endl;
return Guess;
}


void PrintIntro() 
{
// introduce a game
constexpr int WORD_LENGTH = 5;
cout << "Welcome to Bulls and Cow, a fun word game.\n";
cout << "Can you guess the " << WORD_LENGTH;
cout << " letter isogram I'm thinking of?\n";
cout << endl;
}

void PlayGame()
{
// loop five guesses of turn
constexpr int Number_Five = 5;
for (int x = Number_Five; x > 0; x--)
{
    string guess = GetGuess();
    cout << endl;
}
}

bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
cout << "Type yes to play again or no to exit: ";
string Response = "";
getline(cin, Response);

constexpr int Number_One = 1;
constexpr int Number_Zero = 0;

int  Answer_One = 1;
int Answer_Zero = 0;

string True = "Yes";
string False = "No";

string the_answer_1 = "";
string the_answer_2 = "";

// This is the divider I am not done with this shit.... 

Response[0] == 'y' || 'Y';
Response[1] == 'n' || 'N';

Response[0] = Number_One;
Response[1] = Number_Zero;

Response[0] = Answer_One;
Response[1] = Answer_Zero;

Answer_One = Number_One;
Answer_Zero = Number_Zero;

the_answer_1 = Response[0];
the_answer_2 = Response[1];

the_answer_1 = True;
the_answer_2 = False;

Response = the_answer_1;
Response = the_answer_2;

cout << (Response);
cout << endl;
return false;
}
```

Comment: I am only having problems with the BOOLEAN part.

Comment: What boolean part? Your code sets `False` to `"No"`, then `the_answer_2` to `False`, then `Response` to `the_answer_2`, then prints `Response`. Of course that says `"No"`.

Comment: I know you are just experimenting, but the expression `Response[0] == 'y' || 'Y'` is equal to `(Response[0] == 'y') || 'Y'`, which will *always* be true.

Comment: `constexpr int Number_One = 1;` -- good, now we're ready for when one suddenly becomes 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up Response[0] is the first character of the string "Response", and Response[1] is the second character of the string, and so on. If you typed in "Cat" then Response[0] would be 'C' and Response[1] would be 'a', and Response[2] would be 't'. The index is the offset from the start of the string. Take note, it's a basic thing about how strings work.

Basically *everything* inside your "bool AskToPlayAgain()" function is gibberish that doesn't actually do anything meaningful.

Note for matching multiple possibilities you need to be *explicit* when using predicate logic. You can't write e.g. "the sky is blue OR grey", you need to write "the sky is blue OR the sky is grey". "OR" as a logical/mathematical operator is computed after the individual clauses, so they need to be independently verifiably true/false things on either side of the OR operator.

Here's a sample of how it's done:

```
bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
    bool chosenResponse = false; // doesn't matter what this starts as
    bool correctInput = false; // set to true when we know the input was an allowed one

    while(correctInput == false) // keep looping until we get a good one
    {
        cout << "Type (y)es to play again or (n)o to exit: ";
        string Response;
        getline(cin, Response);

        // you want to compare the first character to n,N, y or Y
        // "Response[0]" is the first character of the input

        if(Response[0] == 'y' || Response[0] == 'Y')
        { 
            chosenResponse = true;
            correctInput = true;
        }
        else if(Response[0] == 'n' || Response[0] == 'N')
        { 
            chosenResponse = false;
            correctInput = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "I didn't quite get that, can you try again ...\n\n";
        }
    } // here it loops back if the input didn't match the allowed ones

    return chosenResponse; // if we got out of the loop we know the user typed something beginning with y or Y, or n or N, which is good enough
}
```